# How do I make a sprite node point to a different sprite?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I want to change sprites when the user swipes left and right. Everything I found on stack overflow talks about changing textures. However I want to change the sprite completely.

here is my code that tries to do that

```
@implementation GameScene
SKSpriteNode* player;
SKSpriteNode* playerL;
SKSpriteNode* playerR;

- (void) addPlayer
{
    //player right
    playerR = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed: @"pummelManTestR.png"];
    playerR.scale = 0.2f;
    playerR.name = playerCategoryName;
    playerR.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)*1.3f, playerR.frame.size.height *1.4f);

    //player left
    playerL = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed: @"pummelManTestL.png"];
    playerL.scale = 0.2f;
    playerL.name = playerCategoryName;
    playerL.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)*1.3f, playerL.frame.size.height *1.4f);

//set the starting player position
player = playerL;

[self addChild:player];  
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint endPosition = [touch locationInNode:self];

    if (touchStartPoint.x < endPosition.x && player != playerR) {
        // Right swipe
        //change the image for the player to the other side
        player = playerR;
        NSLog(@"right");


    } else if (touchStartPoint.x > endPosition.x && player != playerL){
        // Left swipe
        //change the image for the player to the other side
        player = playerL;

        NSLog(@"left");

    }
}
```

the NSLogs print the correct information but the sprite on the screen doesn't change.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to change sprites so you can display a right and left image of your player?

Comment: Yes. But I also want to change the position of the player along with the right and left image of it. Do you think I am over complicating the code?

Comment: Then instead of using "player" to hold both nodes, just add one node as needed and removeFromParent when it's no longer needed. You can then add the other node in its place.

Comment: Interesting. I'll make sure to try that out. Thanks for the help, I think that is going to fix it :)

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do but for down the road, you should really just use 1 SKSpriteNode with a texture (as its image). That way you can easily replace the texture at any time and keep the same node. You cannot do that with an image.

Comment: follow up question: is constantly removing and adding nodes less efficient than constantly changing the image and the position of a node?

Comment: Sprites were made to move, all the time if need be. As for adding and removing nodes, it comes down to what is easier for you to track and organize in your code. Think of it this way, a SKSpriteNode is made to move and change its texture many times a second. That's how you create, for example, a running animation for your player. I would not worry about efficiency at this point but rather logical and organized code in your app.

Answer (score 0):

```
player.texture = "your image"
player.name = "your name"
....
```

redefine the element, with this solution i'm test! all right!